# Double tunnel hop via SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm using WinSSHTerm to connect to a proxy, from which I then connect to a server hosting a data warehouse. I just can't figure out how to reproduce my Putty connection using a shell command.

**Short recap:**

I first connect to the proxy server which maps the port 5432 to my local port 10001. After that, i connect to the database server and map its 5432 port to my proxy's 5432 port, which I previously mapped to my 10001 port locally. I am then able to connect to the databse via a database manager locally.

To do so:

I created the following connection to my proxy server first.

[image]

I then added a tunnel from there to my localhost port 10001.

[image]

Once I'm logged in to the proxy server, I use the following command to connect to the database server and map its 5432 port to the proxy's 5432 port.

```
ssh username@databaseServer -L 127.0.0.1:5432:databaseServer:5432
```

I'd like to leave putty and move to WinSSHterm, predefine some login commands for a specific server.

**How may I reproduce the behavior above using a shell command?**

Here's my initial try, which is unfortunately not working:

```
ssh username@databaseServer -L 127.0.0.1:5432:databaseServer:5432
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find the correct way to write it.

**Login Cmds**

```
ssh username@databaseServer -L 127.0.0.1:5432:databaseServer:5432
```

**Cmd-line Args**

```
-L 10001:localhost:5432
```